# Heroku Cli не работает в терминале venv Pycharm

Tags: python, django, heroku

В терминале heroku нормально работает. Но в терминале Pycharm'а пишет что он не найден

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\Desktop\python_work\learning_log>heroku login
"heroku" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Установи Heroku CLI https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli и перезагрузи комп.